# Apache Tomcat cannot be started as a non-root user

Tags: permissions, apache2, users, tomcat6

I manually started Apache Tomcat 6 via the command `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh` and this is the result -

> Using CATALINA_BASE: /home/getx/Desktop/apache-tomcat-6.0.37
>   Using CATALINA_HOME: /home/getx/Desktop/apache-tomcat-6.0.37
>   Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/getx/Desktop/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/temp
>   Using JRE_HOME: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
>   Using CLASSPATH: /home/getx/Desktop/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/bin/bootstrap.jar

However, when I enter `localhost:8080` in Firefox, nothing shows up.

It works when I run the command via `sudo` .

So I guessed it must be due to a permissions problem.

These are my permissions for my current user -

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 getx getx 4096 Jan 18 12:50 bin 
drwxr-xr-x 3 getx getx 4096 Jan 21 21:08 conf 
drwxr-xr-x 2 getx getx 4096 Jan 18 12:50 lib 
-rw-r--r-- 1 getx getx 37951 Apr 29 2013 LICENSE 
drwxr-xr-x 2 getx getx 4096 Jan 21 21:08 logs 
-rw-r--r-- 1 getx getx 558 Apr 29 2013 NOTICE 
-rw-r--r-- 1 getx getx 9188 Apr 29 2013 RELEASE-NOTES 
-rw-r--r-- 1 getx getx 16287 Apr 29 2013 RUNNING.txt 
drwxr-xr-x 2 getx getx 4096 Jan 18 12:50 temp 
drwxr-xr-x 7 getx getx 4096 Apr 29 2013 webapps 
drwxr-xr-x 3 getx getx 4096 Jan 21 21:08 work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got to the root of the problem after viewing the Apache logs in `$CATALINA_HOME/logs`.

This was shown in the logs when I started Apache Tomcat -

`/home/getx/Desktop/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/bin/catalina.sh: 373: /home/getx/Desktop/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/bin/catalina.sh: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin//bin/java: not found`

It appears that Apache Tomcat mysteriously adds its own `/bin/java`.

Removing `/bin/java` from my $JAVA_HOME variable solved the issue.

Using `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/` as the $JAVA_HOME variable worked.